# NodeMailer Request timeout on Heroku (Mandrill, SMTP), works on localhost

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, smtp, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer in an express / angular app and tried a few things with a basic mailer, using `nodemailer`.
I tried using `Hotmail` as the service and it worked on localhost but on heroku
it would constantly return `503` or `Invalid Credentials` even though it worked.

Second I'm trying to hook it up with my Mandrill Account, the code looks like this:

Angular (ES6):

```
sendEmail(form) {

var data = {
  contactName: form.name,
  contactEmail: form.email,
  comments: form.comments || null
};

var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 // url: 'http://localhost:9030/email', <- my express port
 url: location.origin + '/email',
 // url: 'https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/email', <- my heroku app
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 data: data
};

this.$http(req)
.then((result) => {
  console.log('success is...', result);
  return result;
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('error is...', error);
  return error;
});
```

}

Express:

```
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: 'Mandrill', // use well known service.
    // If you are using @gmail.com address, then you don't
    // even have to define the service name
    auth: {
        user: "xxxxx@gmail.com",
        pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
});

console.log('SMTP Configured');

var message = {

    // sender info
    from: 'Sender: <' + req.body.contactEmail + '>',

    // Comma separated list of recipients
    to: '"Info:" <info@example.com>',

    // Subject of the message
    subject: 'Nodemailer is unicode friendly ✔', //

    headers: {
        'X-Laziness-level': 1000
    },

    // plaintext body
    text: "Interest\n" +
        "===========\n" +
        "\n" +
        "**How** are you?"
};

console.log('Sending Mail');
transport.sendMail(message, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error occured');
        console.log(error.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Message sent successfully!');

    // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore, uncomment following line
    transport.close(); // close the connection pool
});
```

I'm really stuck and it feels like a simple task, works on localhost but not on heroku. With the Mandrill SMTP when I send something in the form, I get these logs on heroku:

```
2015-08-24T15:12:58.800676+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /email - - ms - -
2015-08-24T15:13:15.858302+00:00 app[web.1]: { contactName: 'testing',
2015-08-24T15:13:15.858307+00:00 app[web.1]:   contactEmail: 'asdf@adsf.com',
2015-08-24T15:13:15.858309+00:00 app[web.1]:   comments: 'asdfasdf' }
2015-08-24T15:13:15.858316+00:00 app[web.1]: Email params (name):testing
2015-08-24T15:13:15.858376+00:00 app[web.1]: Email params (email):asdf@adsf.com
2015-08-24T15:13:15.858417+00:00 app[web.1]: Email params (comments):asdfasdf
2015-08-24T15:13:15.858498+00:00 app[web.1]: SMTP Configured
2015-08-24T15:13:15.858537+00:00 app[web.1]: Sending Mail
2015-08-24T15:13:15.889774+00:00 app[web.1]: Message sent successfully!
2015-08-24T15:13:45.845230+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/email" host=secret-river-5414.herokuapp.com request_id=5c1e8378-6971-4253-86e2-a9647fc7e0d4 fwd="14.200.153.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-08-24T15:13:45.857582+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /email - - ms - -
```

Please if someone could shed some light, thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Okay, so in case anybody else runs into this, 
I found it was really just a problem with the free hosting I was using.
Heroku timed out my request because it took too long to complete the action, which closes the connection pool for the mailer. I noticed the email came through eventually but at a much later time.

This was rectified by simply upgrading the hosting plan / scaling dynos and increasing workers

Comment: Wrong Solution.